# In a Rails Model, will belongs_to cause a rollback if not defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, activemodel

**Model:**

```
class UserPosition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job_title
end
```

**UserPosition's schema:**

```
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :company_id
  t.integer :industry_id
  t.integer :department_id
  t.integer :job_title_id
  t.string  :job_title_custom
```

**user_positions_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @user_position = UserPosition.find_or_create_by(user_id: current_user.id)
    @user_position.update_attributes({
      :industry_id => params[:industry_id],
      :department_id => params[:department_id],
      :job_title_id => params[:job_title_id],
      :job_title_custom => params[:job_title_custom]
    })
```

I need UserPosition to either create a record with:

```
user_id
job_title_custom
```

OR

```
t.integer :user_id
t.integer :company_id
t.integer :industry_id
t.integer :department_id
t.integer :job_title_id
```

Currently, if I try to create a UserPosition with just `user_id` & `job_title_custom`

It doesn't work, the logs show `ROLLBACK` the error message is:

```
@messages={:job_title=>["must exist"]}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I think it could be because job_title has a relationship defined in the model but the Rails Guide says that they are optional, so I'm not sure.

Comment: I should add, I do have a JobTitle model, job_title_custom is for the user to manually enter any string they want.

Comment: Do you have any validation on UserPosition?  If so and if the validation fails, the `find_or_create_by` is going to roll back.  And I assume from your code, a user can have only one user_position, right?

Comment: Is this a Rails 5 app? Is the association on the job_title table a belongs_to association?

Comment: Did you try the [`errors`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html) method on `@user_position`?

Comment: Like SteveTurczyn wrote, it seems like you are trying to create a UserPosition with just a user_id with the find_or_create_by(user_id: current_user.id) method.  Without seeing the code its hard to know why you're not seeing an error message

Comment: @SteveTurczyna user can have multiple user_positions.

Comment: UserPosition has no validations, right now just `  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job_title`

Comment: @MatayoshiMariano .errors provided nothing useful

Comment: @hashrocket this is a Rails 5 app. JobTitle has: `  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :departments
  has_many :user_positions
  has_many :users, through: :user_positions

  validates_presence_of :title
  validates :title, uniqueness: true

Comment: ALL my mistake, I was logging .errors for the wrong record... I am now seeing the error after trying to create: `@messages={:job_title=>["must exist"]}`

Comment: This is when I try to create a UserPosition w just (user_id, job_title_custom) why is this job_title error occurring?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is a new Rails 5 behavior.

"In Rails 5, whenever we define a belongs_to association, it is required to have the associated record present by default after this change.

It triggers validation error if associated record is not present."

"In Rails 4.x world To add validation on belongs_to association, we need to add option required: true ."

"Opting out of this default behavior in Rails 5. We can pass optional: true to the belongs_to association which would remove this validation check."

Full Answer: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html

Comment: This makes sense to preserve database and data integrity.